# Page not found for newly requested Teams Basic product

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

We've freshly requested a `SO for Teams` instance to give it a spin in our workflow. I have received a registration email and completed the registration process.

The url shown during registration was `stackoverflow.com/c/raiden` -However, trying to access the instance yields a 404 :( .

Do I need to take further steps in order to post/read/access this instance? Or am I simply too impatient?

Comment: It looks like a Team with that name never got created, that's why accessing the URL gives you a 404. I cannot find any errors in our logs either so I can't really tell if anything went wrong. Can you try again to [create your Teams instance](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)? Once you've created your Team successfully, you should see a page saying "Your Team has been created!" and your Team should be available for you instantaneously. If that doesn't work out, would you mind sending an email to **teams@stackoverflow.com**? That way we can better help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

After repeating the sign-up process, the team was created and is accessible.